# how to make reusable listview builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, widget

I have a separate file, in which i have defined both names and images of TWO menus.
newMenu and oldMenu

I have currently a list view and its working fine. but its showing one menu and i dont want to rewrite the whole listview builder widget. is there anyway to make the listview builder widget reusable.

```
Widget selection(String title, String image,) {
return Container(
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: oldMenu.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                },
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                          color: AppTheme.colors.greyFontColor),
                    ),
                    leading: SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            scale: 1,
                            image: Svg(
                              image,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })));
```

}

now if i use the widget name in body like this **selection()** here i can only add string, but i want to add something like this to read the menu item dynamically.
**selection(oldMenu[index].name , oldMenu[index].image)** but the problem is that it shows and error saying **index** is not defined. if its possible then i can reuse the same code and just change the list.

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can include another parameter that will be used for list

```dart
Widget selection(
  String title,
  String image,
  List item,//you can include your dataType
) {
```

And use `item` whenever need to access data.

```dart
 itemCount: item.length,
```

Comment: if i use this widget in other place, i will call it **selection(oldMenu[index].name, oldMenu[index].image)** but this show an error. i can not use index in a string value. how can i reuse this widget other lists.

Comment: I think it will be `selection(item[index].name, item[index].image) ` if you fails, can you include full sample snippet that will raise the issue